What causes the failure to display this Angular 16 loading spinner?
I am making an application-level "loading spinner" with the help of the HttpInterceptor in Angular 16.
In app\services\interceptor.service.ts I have:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor,HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

  public intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.spinnerService.hide();
      })
    );
  }
}

In app\services\spinner.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpinnerService {
  private spinnerCounter = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  spinnerCounter$ = this.spinnerCounter.asObservable();

  public show() {    
    this.spinnerCounter.next(this.spinnerCounter.value + 1);
  }

  public hide() {    
    this.spinnerCounter.next(this.spinnerCounter.value - 1);
  }
}

I have imported the spinnerService in app\app.component.ts and added the spinner to app\app.component.html.
<app-loading-spinner *ngIf="spinnerService.spinnerCounter$ | async"></app-loading-spinner>

Stackblitz
The app-loading-spinner component is never displayed between HTTP requests. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue?

You have to specify that you are providing an HttpInterceptor in your AppModule providers, otherwide it won't do anything on it's own :
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    BypassSanitizePipe,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

Here's the updated StackBlitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lhqg8v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
I'd also like to addres something I saw in your code, when clicking on a movie card, this code snippet runs :
public goToMovieDetails() {
  let movie_url = `/movie/${this.movie.id}`
  window.open(movie_url, '_self');
}

This seems like an odd choice as it is causing quite a lot of side effects, there may be a reason that I'm not seeing from here, but just in case, I'll share the fact that it is possible to redirect using the Angular Router service :
constructor(private movieService: MovieService, private router: Router) { }

public goToMovieDetails() {
  let movie_url = `/movie/${this.movie.id}`
  this.router.navigate([movie_url]);
}

This would avoid any inconvenience like the reloading of the Angular application.
Hope this helps.

Yes, this would be router.push('/movie/3845')
